# How to use us/en instead of en_US with JMSI18nRoutingBundle

Tags: symfony

I'm using JMSI18nRoutingBundle for locale routing on our new site, but our existing site uses language + country in the following format and I need to keep the URLs looking the same.

- example.com/us/en/hello (en_US)
- example.com/be/fr/bonjour (fr_BE)

Is there any way to do this using config?  If not, where is the best place to start customizing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look it's possible to do through config, but it can be done by replacing default implementation of [PatternGenerationStrategyInterface](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/blob/master/Router/PatternGenerationStrategyInterface.php) by your own implementation.

You can check out default implementation that bundle uses [here](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/blob/master/Router/DefaultPatternGenerationStrategy.php).

After you create your own implementation, just make bundle use your own implementation by setting the config parameter. If you're using YAML for example:

```
parameters:
    jms_i18n_routing.pattern_generation_strategy.class: YourBundle\YourImplementationClass
```

Hint: you can basically copy/paste from default implementation and change [line 69](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/blob/master/Router/DefaultPatternGenerationStrategy.php#L69) to use `str_replace('_', '/', $locale)` instead of just `$locale`. That way, newly generated route pattern will contain a `/` if locale contains an `_`.

Not very elegant solution, but bundle unfortunately doesn't provide enough configuration to make it prettier.

Comment: Thanks, Igor! Works like a charm.

Comment: @tomhv Always glad to help :)

Comment: I have requested the ability to add some kind of transform() function (https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle/issues/159)